# PHP dns_get_record wrong?

Tags: php, dns

I've recenlty run into a very strange issue where PHP's `dns_get_record()` function is returning old results.

On the same server, if I use `host` or `dig` from the command line, I get the correct results.

I've even used `dig` to query each individual nameserver and all return the correct current value for the record.

The servers are running Ubuntu 16.04 and are up-to-date.

This is happening on 2 of my servers at Linode, not all of them, so it doesn't sounds like a Linode network thing.

After a few hours, the issue resolved itself without reboot.

There was never a hosts entry for the domain, and to the best of my knowledge, vanilla Ubuntu does not have any built-in DNS cache.

Can anyone explain how PHP's `dns_get_record` works and why it would provide different results from terminal `host` or `dig`?

Comment: It seems probable that the record's TTL played a role here.

Comment: I don't see how this can be TTL related. If it were, `dns_get_record` and `dig` would still agree sporadically. Considering they provide different values consistently, there must be separate lookup and/or caching mechanisms at work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have such extensive knowledge but you may try a library.
Eg. [bluelibraries/dns](https://github.com/bluelibraries/dns)

This library allow you to use 4 types of DNS handlers.

1. **PHP** default ***dns_get_record***()
2. **DIG** (if your system may run this command)
3. **UDP** - ***raw server calls*** (good only responses are smaller than 512 Bytes
4. **TCP** - ***raw server calls*** (personally, ***I would recommend this one***).

You can try different calls with different handlers in the same time then you can compare the result and to pick the one which works for you.

Eg:

#### Retrieve records using `dns_get_record`, `DIG`, `UDP` and `TCP`

```php
// PHP -> dns_get_record()
$records = DNS::getRecords('bluelibraries.com', RecordTypes::TXT, DnsHandlerTypes::DNS_GET_RECORD);

// DIG command
$records = DNS::getRecords('bluelibraries.com', RecordTypes::TXT, DnsHandlerTypes::DIG);

// UDP
$records = DNS::getRecords('bluelibraries.com', RecordTypes::TXT, DnsHandlerTypes::UDP);

//TCP
$records = DNS::getRecords('bluelibraries.com', RecordTypes::TXT);
```

#### One response example

```
Array
(
    [0] => BlueLibraries\Dns\Records\Types\Txt\DomainVerification Object
        (
            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [host] => bluelibraries.com
                    [class] => IN
                    [ttl] => 0
                    [type] => TXT
                    [txt] => google-site-verification=test-636b-4a56-b349-test
                )
        )
)
```